# Entering to context manager with method of instance

Tags: python, oop, contextmanager

I would like to implement a context manager in my class that wouldn't create a new instance but would be invoked on an existing one using a certain method,

so that in usage, it would look as follows:

```py
some_instance = SomeClass()

with some_instance.context_manager_method():
    ... # do something
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can use `contextlib.contextmanager` to create any context manager that you want. Here's a snippet:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

class SomeClass:
    @contextmanager
    def context_manager_method(self):
        # setup
        yield
        # teardown
```